# How do I output unescaped HTML with javascript in Laravel Blade?

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a VUEX store and a blog post that I need to output.

I use CKEditor for the input but I can't output the raw HTML with the `@{{ }}` in the front-end.

I have already tried to use `@{{!! !!}}` but apparently these doesn't work together.

This is the line that I output: 
`<div>@{{ $store.state.item.conteudo }}</div>`

And this is the actual output of the code:

[`<p><strong>Teste Laravel</strong></p>`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkxrb.png)

Comment: what is the front end you are using?

Answer (score 1):

You're using double bracket so, You should try `{!! !!}` instead of `{{!! !!}}`.

So now your variable looks like.

```
{!! $text !!}
```

Check more info. [displaying data](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#displaying-data)

Comment: Tried and it didn't show.

I'm getting the data in JavaScript from VUEX Store.I send data from the 

I want to output an html code but I can't use the.

Comment: Tried and it didn't show.

Thanks @Dilip-hirapara

I send data from a view button inside a table to a modal. And the modal shows the HTML input without a page refresh.

I want to output an html code from JavaScript but I can't use the output PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

you can also do like this by using getter in your model

Hope it help!

```
public function getConteudoAttribute($value) {
    return html_entity_decode($value);
}
```